# How to promote frame based application in google Search

Tags: search, meta-tags, google-search

We have a Sportmanagement web application, that is using Classic ASP technology.
Our users can access their account using a html link.I mean the main url of our application is http://www.sportsmanager.us and users access their account using following links
http://www.sportsmanager.us/MOHA.htm
and many more...
and now we want to promote these links on google search.I don't how google search work and what I should do for better search.The application's html page uses frameset and has three frames.Top Frame, Left Frame and Right Frame. Please try any above link and let me know where I should put search keywords and what other things I should do.

Comment: You should learn that frames aren't used anymore (haven't been used for like a decade or so)..

Answer (score 2):

First up, a link for you. http://seoforums.org/  As a forum dedicated to search engine optimization you can probably find a lot of what you are looking for there.

Unfortunatly the fact that you are using frames makes search engine optimization a bit tricky.  It becomes harder for the spiders/robots to crawl and index your site properly.  If i recall correctly Inktomi and AltaVista wont even bother if they see frames.

The problem is that the links leading to other frames use a src attribute instead of a href which many search engines struggle to index through.

With this in mind you should try and get your keywords into the main frame.  That is the frame that loads first before all others, as this will be all that some engines can reach.

http://searchenginewatch.com/2167931 This link describes using meta tags in relation to keywords for search engines

http://www.seologic.com/faq/frames-html-links.php This link describes how frames will impact search engines indexing attempts

EDIT: halfdan does have a valid point in his comment above.  Frames are somewhat unfashionable these days, these issues probably contributing.  For alternatives you might want to inspect AJAX to dynamically load sections of your page without full refreshes